# Why is the "PREVIEW" button shown in products structured data?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

After I implemented JSON-LD format for products on my website, I could see the following **preview button** on Google Structured Data Testing Tool:

> [image: Preview Button for Product]

I hope Google has implemented Rich Cards for just Articles, Recipes and Video till now. Does it mean that Rich cards for Products are on the way?
Note: The products structured data is shown in Google Search Console and has no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Google offers a [product rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products) for Google Search and for Google Images.

It makes use of Schema.org’s `Product` and `Offer`/`AggregateOffer` (and, optionally, `AggregateRating` and `Review`) types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to kindly ask you whether rich cards are for products or not. If no, then why does google mention products in the following statement?

"Rich cards are a good way to provide data to Google Search about events, products, or opportunities on your website. Rich card data can be displayed to users in a variety of formats on different devices, and can help drive traffic to your website."

And also when we click on "Get started with rich cards" button, it redirects you to search gallery that contain products.

That means it wont be detected as rich cards?

Comment: @SamanShakya: May or may not be the case, I don’t know. A rich card is a specific form of a rich result, but Google’s documentation doesn’t seem to be as specific as possible.